# Convert and substring in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help to get my syntax-correct in a SQL query, I want to use `Substring` and `convert`, but in the convert I also convert the date into format 112.

```
where Substring(Convert(varchar(100),Datum,12,16,112)) = '8:00'
```

My code above.

EDIT Explanation

I've wrote a stored procedure that stores data in one place, this data I later called upon from another stored procedure in order too get statistics, the stored procedure is executed from an ERP system once the user chooses this particular report, the purpose is to give data 2 times a day to see if it gets more or less.

Cheers

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: If `Datum` is actually a `datetime` value, why not just cast it to `time` and do a direct comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your `CONVERT` first, then wrap that in the `SUBSTRING`

```
WHERE Substring(Convert(varchar(100),Datum,112),12,16) = '8:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must do Convert(varchar(100),Datum,112) and then put it in Substring. Try like this;

```
 WHERE Substring(Convert(varchar(100),Datum,112),12,16) = '8:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find `datum` values where the hour is `8` and the minutes `0`.

If so, try this:

```
where datepart(hour, datum) = 8 and datepart(minute, datum) = 0
```